What does "I them" mean in "I have 6 grandchildren that are not blood relatives who have always loved me as their grandpa and I them"?
What does the second part of the sentence, "and I them." mean?
Is it grammatically correct? Please explain.

"They loved me and I (loved) them."  The repeated verb is omitted.

Where's the sentence from?

I got this sentence from yahoo comments, but I have seen this kind of usage before. I just think it's interesting to see two pronouns being put next to each other. Thanks for looking into my question!!!
